# How to fix DEX 64K Methods Limit in minSdkVersion 21?

Tags: java, android

I got this error while creating APK file:

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I referenced to this [tutorial](http://www.akexorcist.com/2016/02/dex-with-over-65k-and-multidex-on-android-en.html) to fix this issue but I still get this error.

I used MultiDex in my project like this:

in biuld.gradle for sdk 16:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.saly.test"

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
}
```

in Manifest for sdk 16:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        ...

    </application>
   </manifest>
```

now I get the new error:

> Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR: Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:289)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:491)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:772)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1700)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:755)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:723)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1653)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
>   Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>   Error:    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED Error:Execution failed for
>   task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 3

then I changed my minimum sdk to 21 for fixing this error but it's not working.

this is my build.gradle for sdk 21:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.saly.test" 

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
}
```

How can I fix this error?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these lines

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

in your gradle script anywhere inside

```
android { 
....

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is add:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and this to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**or if you have** your own implementation of `Application` class, override `attachBaseContext` method inside `Application` like that:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did this before but as I describe I get the new error `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR`